# Почему не сохраняется картинка из Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

`Add logo` добавляет картинку, а `Download` должен скачивать, но он не работает:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Up () {//загрузка
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
 src = "http://chu93.aphp.fr/wp-content/blogs.dir/32/files/2015/10/LOGO-YOUTUBE.png";
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 480, 400);
    }
}

function download() {//скачиване
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
</head>
<body onload="doCanvas()">
<button type="button" onclick="Up()" >Add logo</button>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">Download</a>
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="config.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя скачивать изображение с `canvas`, если в него добавлена картинка с другого домена, это нарушение безопасности, насколько я понял

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Up () {//загрузка
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#f90';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText('Code Project', 10, canvas.height / 2 - 15);
    ctx.font = '26px sans-serif';
}

function download() {//скачиване
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL();
    this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<button type="button" onclick="Up()" >Add logo</button>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">Download</a>
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="400"></canvas>
```